# Select the amount of billable hours and non-billable hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I started in the database, so be kind to me please. The application that I want to write seems basic, I tried, but I failed.

Here is my problem:
I have this:

Table: Employee

```
# | Colonne | Type | Interclassement | Attributs | Null | Défaut | Extra | Action
1 | Id | int(11) | no | Aucune | AUTO_INCREMENT
2 | Name | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | yes | NULL
3 | Firstname | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | yes | NULL | 
4 | IdNumber | int(11) | yes | NULL
5 | Mail | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | no | Aucune | 
6 | PassWord | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | no | Aucune | 
7 | Site | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | yes | NULL | 
8 | Entrance | date | yes | NULL | 
9 | Departure | date | yes | NULL | 
10 | Car_Id | int(11) | yes | NULL | 
11 | Profil_Id | int(11) | yes | NULL |
```

Table : Imputation

```
# | Colonne | Type | Interclassement | Attributs | Null | Défaut | Extra | Action
1 | Id | int(11) | | | no | Aucune | AUTO_INCREMENT
2 | Hours | int(11) | | | yes | NULL | 
3 | Description | varchar(256) | latin1_swedish_ci | | yes | NULL | 
4 | ToBeBilled | tinyint(1) | | | yes | 1 | 
5 | BillNumber | int(11) | | | yes | NULL | 
6 | Day | date | | | yes | NULL | 
7 | TimeSheet_Id | int(11) | | | no | Aucune | 
8 | Project_Id | int(11) | | | no | Aucune | 
9 | automatic | tinyint(1) | | | no | 0 |
```

Table : TimeSheet

```
# | Colonne | Type | Interclassement | Attributs | Null | Défaut | Extra | Action
1 | Id | int(11) | | | no | Aucune | AUTO_INCREMENT
2 | Month | int(2) | | | yes | NULL | 
3 | Year | int(4) | | | yes | NULL | 
4 | Filled | tinyint(1) | | | yes | 0 | 
5 | Closed | tinyint(1) | | | yes | 0
6 | Employee_Id | int(11) | | | no | Aucune |
```

And I want to achieve the following result :

```
________________________________________________________
Name     | Billable hours | Non-billable hours | Total hours
________________________________________________________
John Doe | 872            | 142                | 1014
 ________________________________________________________
```

Billable hours are those with ToBeBilled lines = true. Non-billable hours are ToBeBilled lines = false.

Here is my SQL query that I'm currently working on (I use [FlySpeed ​​SQL Query](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html) tool to help me build my SQL queries) :

```
Select
   Employee.Name,
  Sum( Imputation.Hours),
   Imputation.ToBeBilled
From
   Employee Inner Join
   TimeSheet On  TimeSheet.Employee_Id =  Employee.Id,
   Imputation
Where
   Imputation.ToBeBilled = 'true'
Group By
   Employee.Name,  Imputation.ToBeBilled
Order By
   Employee.Name
```

---

After help, here is the final query :

```
Select
  Employee.Name As Name,
  Sum(Case When Imputation.ToBeBilled = '1' Then Imputation.Hours End) As `Billable`,
  Sum(Case When Imputation.ToBeBilled = '0' Then Imputation.Hours End) As `NonBillable`,
  Sum(Imputation.Hours) As `Total`
From
  Employee Inner Join
  TimeSheet On TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id Inner Join
  Imputation On Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id
Group By
  Employee.Name, Employee.Id
Order By
  Name
```

Comment: Any clues on how to calculate Billable hours | Non-billable hours????

Comment: Do not mix join styles. In fact, do not use comma-join style at all. Also, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: how can you join employee with imputation table?

Comment: Billable hours are those with ToBeBilled lines = true. Non-billable hours are ToBeBilled lines = false.

Comment: can you provide some sample data? and also show the definition of the tables, also with the ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by doing the proper joins between all the tables.  Just *never* use a comma in a `from` statement.  Then do conditional aggregation -- nesting `case` statements in the `sum()`:

```
Select e.Name, Sum( i.Hours) as TotalHours,
       sum(case when i.ToBeBilled = 1 then i.Hours else 0 end) as Billable,
       sum(case when i.ToBeBilled = 0 then i.Hours else 0 end) as NonBillable
From Employee e Inner Join
     TimeSheet ts
     On ts.Employee_Id =  e.Id Inner Join
     Imputation i
     on i.TimeSheetID = ts.TimeSheetId
Group By e.Name, e.id
Order By Employee.Name;
```

This assumes that the values taken by `ToBeBilled` are `0` and `1`.  The inclusion of `e.Id` in the `group by` is to handle the situation where two employees have the same name.

Comment: Your request responds perfectly to my problem. I tried to put two answers as answers, but it is mandatory to choose. Sorry.

Comment: After looking closer at the conditions "= true" and "!=true" proposed by @fthiella, they are not relevant conditions. It is preferable to use "= 0" and "= 1" as conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Employee.Name,
  Sum(CASE WHEN Imputation.ToBeBilled = 'true' THEN Imputation.Hours END) As Billable_hours,
  Sum(CASE WHEN Imputation.ToBeBilled != 'true' THEN Imputation.Hours END) As NonBillable_hours,
  SUM(Imputation.Hours) As total_hours
FROM
  Employee INNER JOIN TimeSheet
  On TimeSheet.Employee_Id =  Employee.Id
  INNER JOIN Imputation
  ON Imputation.TimeSheet_Id=TimeSheet.id
GROUP BY
  Employee.Id, Employee.Name
ORDER BY
  Employee.Name
```

Comment: Simply perfect! I simply copy/paste your query and it works! Thank you for your help !

Comment: After looking closer at the conditions "= true" and "!=true" are not relevant conditions. As suggested by @Gordon Linoff it's best to use "= 0" and "=1" as conditions.

Comment: @axsoverflow if it's a tinyint column, it's better to use "=0" and "=1", or just `CASE WHEN Imputation.ToBeBilled THEN ... END` and `CASE WHEN NOT Imputation.ToBeBilled THEN ... END`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
Select Employee.Name, 

(Select sum(Imputation.Hours) from TimeSheet where (TimeSheet.Employee_Id =  Employee.Id) AND (Imputation.ToBeBilled = 'true')) as BillableHours,

 (Select sum(Imputation.Hours) from TimeSheet where (TimeSheet.Employee_Id =  Employee.Id) AND (Imputation.ToBeBilled = 'false')) as NonBillableHours,

 (Select sum(Imputation.Hours) from TimeSheet where (TimeSheet.Employee_Id =  Employee.Id) ) as TotalHours

FROM Employee
```